# Capture event of modal panel open globally

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

We're busy implementing analytics to our product. One of the things we would like to track is page naviagtion and also modal panel opens (and maybe closes). Since its quite a large product we would like to add this so genericly as possible without having to go over every page and modal panel. For navigation this was quite easy we can just put a $on on rootscope level to track $routeChangeStart or $routeChangeSuccess

My question here is as follows. Does $modalInstance emit a similair kind of event that we can capture on rootscope level.

We have considered to emit a event ourselves on close but this would require us to go over every modal panel ourselves (which there are alot off)

With best regards,
Robin

Comment: `Does $modalInstance emit a similair kind of event`, modals don't emit events, they resolve/reject promises